# A subset $S=\{x\in\mathbb{R}, x\sin x\leq 1, x\cos x\leq 1\}$ of real line

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, trigonometry

Consider a subset $S$ of real numbers $R$ defined as $S$={$x∈R,x\sin x≤1, x\cos x≤1$}. I want to verify that am I right to say that $S$ is unbounded and open?

- **My work:** Since $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are periodic functions over $R$ and as they satisfy the inequalities in the intervals falling in third quadrant of [0,2π] periodically hence $S$ must be unbounded. Further, each interval is closed but as such intervals are infinite hence what can be said about closed or open?

Kindly correct me where I am wrong.

Comment: The set is unbounded, but it is closed. The functions $f: x\mapsto x\sin(x)$ and $g: x\mapsto x\cos(x)$ are both continuous, and you set can be written as $$f^{-1}[1,\infty)\cap g^{-1}[1,\infty)$$ which is the intersection of two closed sets.

Comment: An infinite union of closed intervals is open????

Comment: What's the "third quadrant" and why would periodically falling in it make S unbounded?

Comment: All odd multiples of pi lie in your set S. So the set is unbounded and non-empty. But as Prahlad already said, it is closed. So if it were open also, it would be the whole real line, because the real line is connected. But this is not the case because, for instance pi/2 > 1 is not in the set.

Comment: fleablood..I meant the intervals [(2n+1)π, (2n+3/2)π] where n=0,1,2,...

Comment: This subset, i.e. S won't be an interval in the first place.

Comment: @Prahlad Vaidyanathan..I dnt understand [1,infinity)..

Comment: @Prahlad..Will you please elaborate more?

Comment: If $f$ is a continuous function, try proving that the set $$A := \{x : f(x)\leq 1\}$$ is closed. This set is $f^{-1}(-\infty, 1]$ (there was a typo in my earlier comment)

Comment: As f is continuous and $(-\infty, 1]$ is closed so is $f^(-1)$(-\infty,1]. Is it correct?